# Override abstract method upon instance creation in c#

Tags: c#, java, .net

In java, we can override or implement abstract methods upon instance creation as follows:

```
AbstractClass test =new AbstractClass() 
{
    public void AbstractMethod(string i) {

    }
    public void AbstractMethod2(string i) {

    }
};
```

Is this possible in C#? if Yes, what's the equivalent code

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This Java feature is called ["anonymous class"](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm), not "an override of method on instance creation". There is no identical feature in C#.

C# took a different route - instead of providing convenience syntax for creation of subclasses, it expanded upon its delegate features, providing [anonymous delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). Lambdas let you plug in pieces of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something very similar through clever use of lambdas:

```
public class BaseClass {

    public BaseClass(Action<string> abs1 = null, Action<string> abs2 = null){
       AbstractMethod1 = abs1 ?? s=>{};
       AbstractMethod2 = abs2 ?? s=>{};
    }

    public Action<string> AbstractMethod1 {get; private set;}
    public Action<string> AbstractMethod2 {get; private set;}
}
```

So you could use this definition like so:

```
new BaseClass( s=> Console.WriteLine(s), s=> Console.WriteLine(s));
```

You could also define all the methods as part of an interface and then construct a class with a concrete implementation of the interface (proxying the calls to the concrete implementation) -- I would call that the "Strategy" Pattern. But that's just a variation of this theme.

Comment: This is nice, but not something someone just learning C# should think about :)

Comment: @TDaver, lambda expressions have been part of .net for more than 4 years, they're everywhere. The author is familiar with Java, which has a lambdas, so it's not a new concept, just a slightly different (better?) syntax.

Comment: while I agree with you that lambdas are good and should be used (especially with LINQ), but a beginner has a hard time to actually grasp the class design considerations of a base class like the one you're suggesting :)

Comment: and being in use for a long time means nothing for a beginner. `yield return` has been around longer and I still cannot teach it to less advanced users without some headache :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know `Java`, but this "smells" like [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) in `C#`.

For example, you can write something like:

```
 var myNewType = new { 
                       Name = "Charles", 
                       Surname="Dickens", 
                       Age = 55 
                      };
```

Comment: No, doesn't have much in common with anonymous classes - even if they sound similar.